# Moses tuning fails to run extractor

Tags: machine-learning, machine-translation, moses

When I attempt to tune my Moses tuner (according to the [moses baseline](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.Baseline)), it reaches the end of my tuning dataset (75k lines) and then exits on the code:

```
Executing: /home/alexm/Desktop/dissertation/models/cy-en/transsystem/mert-work/extractor.sh > extract.out 2> extract.err
Exit code: 127
ERROR: Failed to run '/home/alexm/Desktop/dissertation/models/cy-en/transsystem/mert-work/extractor.sh'. at ../../../mosesdecoder/scripts/training/mert-moses.pl line 1775.
```

It exits without giving the current tuning weights too, causing the loss of hours of progress.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing some file or access to it

127 typically means **command not found**

Are you missing the file /home/alexm/Desktop/dissertation/models/cy-en/transsystem/mert-work/extractor.sh ?